# Configure Maven to have two output artifacts OR extract specific folder from JAR during web-application assembly

Tags: maven

I'm migrating existing build system from Ant to Maven, and so far I've solved (or redesigned) many issues, except for this one.
Target of each our system-specific project is a simple JAR, but it additionally contains some project configuration and customizaton information which is copied to a (let's say) `/product` folder of a WAR. This way modularity and extensibility of our web-application is achieved 
Consider example:

```
project: 
  MyProject
    /product
      product.info
      some.data
WAR:
./product
  /MyProject
    product.info
    some.data
    ..
  ..
./WEB-INF/
  /lib
    MyProject.jar
    ..
```

My question is: how do I achieve this result for our product-specific projects? The first thing that comes up my mind is: two artifacts as a result of such project build (JAR and ZIP), where ZIP is created by a POM in `/product` folder (and the best layout would probably be splitting each project into two sub-projects so that I can aggregate POM and ZIP with one multi-module project).  I will appreciate all solutions proposed (incl. project folders' restructuring options).

Comment: Does this mean you have different configuration contained in your product folder for a single war ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm not sure if I have correctly understood your comment, but this is how it works: the configuration is different for different 'subproducts', but one 'product' (you can call it a module if you wish) results in only one JAR and only one sub-folder in ./product folder (again, it can be named as './modules')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and obvious answer is splitting up each such 'product' project (consider it as a 'module' if it's easier to perceive this way) into two sub-projects -- one for JAR, and one for configuration data. Then, using an assembly, all declared 'product-ZIPs' will go to `./product` folder of a WAR.

**EDIT** Classifiers could also be applied to configuration-plugins in order to make assemblies more structured and easier to implement.